# CORS error with AWS api gateway and java lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, httpclient, aws-api-gateway

Today I created one api gateway on aws and one java lambda function. Then finally integrated api gateway with lambda function.
So when I hit the api using postman then it returns the result which is basically a list of customer. Till now everything looks fine. Following is the

```
@Override
    public TestResponse handleRequest(Request input, Context context) {
        TestService testService = SingletonServiceManager.getInstance().getTestService();
        TestListResponse response = (TestListResponse)productListService.executeRequest(input);
        return response;
    }
```

After executing it returns following output.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "products": [

        {
            "name": "test1",
            "code": "test1",
            "status": true
        },
        {
            "name": "test2",
            "code": "test2",
            "status": true
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I started integrating this with api call with Angular from local machine it start throwing CORS issue. Angular client using it CORS setting to connect.

Can someone help me on this. Do I need to enable something special from lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [enable CORS in your API Gateway configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).

Comment: I was enabled but with wrong pattern. Reviewed it and fix it. 
Thanks for help

Comment: hi @Mark, could you please help again on this, strange for the post this solution is not working for me , even after adding OPTIONS method. 
Could you tell me catch.

Comment: Did you redeploy the API Gateway after enabling CORS?

Comment: Are you following this guide? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html There's really nothing else you need to do.